# Dictionary as parameter, where the Value-Type is irrelevant

Tags: c#

I have a function, that returns the next higher value of a Dictionary-Keys-List compared to a given value. If we have a Key-List of {1, 4, 10, 24} and a given value of 8, the function would return 10.

Obviously the type of the Value-Part of the Dictionary doesn't matter for the function, the function-code for a

```
Dictionary<int, int>
```

and

```
Dictionary<int, myClass>
```

would be the same.

How has the method-head have to look like, when I want to call the function with any Dictionary, that has int as key-Type and the value-Type is irrelevant?

I tried:

```
private int GetClosedKey(Dictionary<int, object> list, int theValue);
```

but it says that there are illegal arguments, when I call it with a Dictionary. I don't want to copy'n'paste the function for each different value-type that my function may be called. Any idea, how to accomplish that?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make it generic:

```
private int GetClosedKey<T>(Dictionary<int, T> list, int theValue)
```

In most cases, when you call the method you can use type inference to avoid having to specify the type argument for `T`.

However, I would *consider* changing it to:

```
private int GetClosedKey(ICollection<int> list, int theValue)
```

And then calling it with:

```
int value = GetClosedKey(dictionary.Keys, desiredValue);
```

That makes the code more general - there's no need to couple it tightly with a dictionary, after all. Aside from anything else, that's going to make it simpler to test.

Comment: @Nick: I don't think so; the qusetion isn't particularly clear, but I think it's actually going to return a key, not a value.

Comment: I scrolled past the first full sentence of the question...heh makes a difference.

Comment: My interpretation of what he is going for says this is right for him

Comment: You exactly get what I wanted to say, Jon! Many thanks for the answer. I considered your change suggestion and implemented it that way :)